# How can I get the created by and updated by fields in StrapiJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, strapi

I've just started using StrapiJS, and it's really great so far, but now I've come across a problem.

When creating adding some data to the database, Strapi automatically creates some fields - like `created_by` and `updated_by` fields, but I'm not getting them in the API response.

This is the data stored in MongoDB:

```json
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "606fd90b0057c05954d29f50"
    },
    "likes": 0,
    "dislikes": 0,
    "Title": "Why is this not working?",
    "Subtitle": "I really don't know",
    "slug": "why-is-this-not-working",
    "content": "**I DO NOT KNOW**",
    "published_at": {
        "$date": "2021-04-09T04:33:17.304Z"
    },
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2021-04-09T04:33:15.232Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2021-04-09T04:33:17.316Z"
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "created_by": {
        "$oid": "606f1a45af15265f780983ce"
    },
    "updated_by": {
        "$oid": "606f1a45af15265f780983ce"
    }
}
```

And this is the API response:

```json
{
        "likes": 0,
        "dislikes": 0,
        "_id": "606fd90b0057c05954d29f50",
        "Title": "Why is this not working?",
        "Subtitle": "I really don't know",
        "slug": "why-is-this-not-working",
        "content": "**I DO NOT KNOW**",
        "published_at": "2021-04-09T04:33:17.304Z",
        "createdAt": "2021-04-09T04:33:15.232Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-04-09T04:33:17.316Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "id": "606fd90b0057c05954d29f50"
    }
```

Is there a way to get the created of the data in the API response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to override the findOne method in your controller like below without the sanitize:

```js
async findOne(ctx) {
     const { id } = ctx.params;    
     const entity = await strapi.services.blogPost.findOne({ id });
     // return sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.blogPost});
     return entity;
}
```

refer:[Backend customization](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html#controllers)

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: how to use this on Strapi v4?

Answer (score 2):

`populateCreatorFields=true` doesn't work anymore for Strapi v4.
So here is the full answer for the Strapi v4.

Customize the Backend controller (documentation: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/backend-customization/controllers) by using the code from this link https://forum.strapi.io/t/cant-get-createdby-from-api/15687 on this file `/src/api/<your_api_name>/controllers/<your_api_name>.ts`.

Let's say you have `/article` API.
Just replace `article` with your API name.

```js
'use strict';

/**
 *  article controller
 */

const { createCoreController } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreController('api::article.article', ({ strapi }) => ({
  async find(ctx) {
    // Calling the default core action
    const { data, meta } = await super.find(ctx);

    const query = strapi.db.query('api::article.article');

    await Promise.all(
      data.map(async (item, index) => {
        const article = await query.findOne({
          where: {
            id: item.id,
          },
          populate: ['createdBy'],
        });
        
        data[index].attributes.createdBy = {
          id: article.createdBy.id,
          firstname: article.createdBy.firstname,
          lastname: article.createdBy.lastname,
        };
      })
    );

    return { data, meta };
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

set `populateCreatorFields=true` in model.settings.json

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work for me

Add

```
"populateCreatorFields": true
```

Add Optional

```
"publicAttributes": ["created_at", "updated_by"]
```

to

api/blog-post/models/blog-post.settings.json

...

```
"options": {
    "increments": true,
    "timestamps": true,
    "draftAndPublish": true,
    "populateCreatorFields": true
  }
```

...

[image]

Comment: I tried this on Strapi v4.15.5 and didn't work