# [Strapi v4]: How to GET content created by a particular user in Strapi CMS

Tags: node.js, content-management-system, strapi, headless-cms

I have a use-case of retrieving content that is created by a particular user. Whenever I try GETng it, I am getting all the data created by different user.

Scenario 1:

1. I have an `admin` user. I created a content type of stock-list with name and description field.
2. I created 5 rows of data as per stock-list content type.

Scenario 2:

1. I have another user say `testA`.
2. I have created 4 rows of stock-list content by logging in as testA.

Now I wanted to retrieve stock list created by userA. Supposing I have a public endpoint for getting GET /stock-lists, how can I GET that ?
Currently when I am firing GET /stock-lists, I am getting all the data created by admin and testA user combined.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Here is the answer for Strapi v4 https://stackoverflow.com/a/77699026/8339172

Answer (score 0):

does the stock list have a relationship with a user.if not make a relationship of one user having many stocks then you can make a query by finding all the stocks with a specific user.