# How do I add an "author" field in the strapi cms?

Tags: strapi

I can't figure out how to set up the links. I have created a collection. I need an creator to be automatically specified in that record when adding a record to the collection. How do I do that?

Comment: The `created by` field contains detail about the person who created the record

Comment: @Isfaaq There is no such field

Comment: Here is the answer for Strapi v4 https://stackoverflow.com/a/77699026/8339172

Answer (score 4):

I've faced this problem...

I found the solution in the documentation:

need to add

> "populateCreatorFields": true

in the file (strapi v3) /api/your-type-name/models/your-type-name.settings.json

in options object

like:

```
...
   "options": {
    "increments": true,
    "timestamps": true,
    "draftAndPublish": true,
    "populateCreatorFields": true
   },
...
```

More information can be found at [strapi documentation](https://docs-v3.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html#model-options)

Comment: Текс... У меня нет папки models

Comment: ага, у меня 4 версия...

Comment: you need to update strapi to V4.3.0+

https://github.com/strapi/strapi/pull/13819

Comment: I tried this on Strapi v4.15.5 but didn't work

Comment: in version 4 you can take parameters from a get request like GET /api/posts?populate=*

More details can be found in the documentation:
https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/rest/populate-select#populating-createdby-and-updatedby
if you use graphql the solution is here
https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/12228#issuecomment-1041121410

Answer (score 0):

Strapi does not support it by default. As mentioned in this [form](https://forum.strapi.io/t/auto-fill-created-by-field/293) you can achieve it by editing the strapi's controller. But I will not recommend you to edit the strapi controller at all. Please avoid it.

There is a simple and better solution to this. You can achieve this by creating `one to one relationship`. Create an author table/collection. Make one to one relationship with your `other collection`. You can make it a required option as well. So whenever someone creates an entry they have to select an author from your already created collection of `authors`.
And now you can get relation in your **API** and use it wherever you want to.

Comment: I want to create a site with ads where regular users can post ads. And you're suggesting that I make it so that any user can post ads on any behalf.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment, Strapi (tested on v3) comes with a `created by` field. To ascertain the claim, the following steps can be followed;

1. Create a new content type. Here I am setting only one field, called test
   [image]
2. Add an entry for that content type. Notice the `last update` and `by` field on the right.
   [image]
3. Save and open the entry. The `last update` and `by` fields have been automatically populated.
   [image]

Comment: get query "http://localhost:1337/api/tests"
There is no created_by in this query. 
Try a get query and tell me if you get created_by?

Comment: I cannot fetch the `createdBy` via the api